# sql select, get cars which are due a job

Tags: sql, mysql, database

My database consists of 2 tables. Im using MySQL.

Table 1

cars = id(int,PRIMARYKEY), reg(int), type(int)

Table 2

jobs = ref(int,PRIMARYKEY), id (int), date(date)

I need a SELECT statement which would get me all the cars which have not had a job in the past 3 weeks.

(i.e: If a car has not had a job in the past 3 weeks, then that car(id) would be returned.)

I know there would be several ways to do this however I am not up to speed in sql yet :<

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a good use case for `NOT EXISTS`:

```
select c.id,c.reg,c.type
from cars c
where not exists 
(
  select NULL
  from jobs j
  where j.id = c.id
  and j.date >= CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 3 WEEK
);
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what flavour of Oracle you are using but this would work on Oracle. In other flavours you'd have to work out your date in a different way (and maybe the join syntax is a little different).

```
select *
from cars c
 left join jobs j 
  on j.id = c.id
where j.date < sysdate - 21
```

Comment: Even if you translate `sysdate - 21` to MySQL, it's not going to give you the data you want. This will return cars that had jobs more than 3 weeks ago,not cars without a job int eh past 3 weeks.

Comment: Well, it returns everything that's not had a job in the last 3 weeks. Including cars that have not had a job at all. Not what was requested I guess.

Answer (score 0):

If the link between both tables is the jobs.ref, then the sql could be like this:

```
   select id from cars where id in 
    (select ref from jobs where date < DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAl 21 DAY)
```

Comment: the link between tables if actually id(int)

Comment: This will return cars which had a job more than 3 weeks ago. What the OP wants is to see cars which **have not** had a job in the past 3 weeks.